# Is it required for iptables nat to forward icmp and other protocols?

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding

Some examples of iptables configuration for NAT gives no information about forwarding ICMP packets, some manuals suggest

```
-A FORWARD -i in -o out  -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8  -j ACCEPT
```

ufw configuration (even though it's not used as router) in filter.FORWARD subchain have following

```
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
```

So what is right? And what about other protocols like igmp, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess these things: NAT is for address translation, the default `iptables` table `filter` is about filtering packets.

If the question is: which filter do I need in order to make NAT working? The answer is: none. There are no such links between tables. Of course, you need to add rules in order to make packets **flow thru** your system, otherwise the NAT component will be ready but idle (no filter = no packets).

So, NAT will works even if you prohibit ICMP and other protocols. Of course, some ICMP messages are useful in order to make things works (for example, the path MTU discovery uses ICMP, and if you block all ICMP messages, the connection is very broken). Still, this have nothing to do with NAT: you have the same problems even if you don't use NAT and you mess with `filter` table.

You can find some information about ICMP blocking here: http://shouldiblockicmp.com

In short you may want to allow:

- Echo Request/Reply
- Fragmentation required
- Time Exceeded

In IPv6 you need to allow also NDP and SLAAC.

Comment: if I formulate question like this: Which ICMP packets are required to be allowed to pass iptables based router in order to make network work properly?

Comment: You can find some information here: http://shouldiblockicmp.com/
In short: Echo Request/Reply, Fragmentation required and Time Exceeded (for IPv4). In IPv6 you need to allow also NDP and SLAAC.

Comment: could you please append this to your answer?

Comment: Yes, of course. Text added :-)